# How to pass hidden data in php email subject line?

Tags: php, email, mime-types, email-headers

As I want to handle email failure and in that case when you send mail to other and if it gets in failure because of invalid to-email or etc. reason. In that case I can't see my email body in failure but I can see only subject line. So for that I want to pass hidden data in php email subject line.

Comment: In what way do you think the data could be hidden?

Comment: what's problem with retrieving data from `$_POST`? what you want to get finally? can you show code?

Comment: [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path), may well be what you need, you create a return address with a code in it, and use that  code to get what ever information you require. commonly used in mailing lists and other mailing software for tracking returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible to pass hidden data in subject line

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hide data in the E-Mail subject.

The best you can do is include a code, and store additional information about this code in your database. When you are returned an E-Mail, you can use the code to look up the data.

That's the way many support systems work. The messages they send out will be in the form

```
(#1234567) Your support request
```

they are then able to parse out the `1234567` and look up the info, associate the reply with a customer, etc.

Comment: can't i write any html tag and set css to display:none or any other way?

Comment: @Nikunj in an E-Mail subject? No. No E-Mail client interprets HTML in subject lines.